# SharePoint Installation 3tier

Tags: sharepoint-server

While installing the SharePoint Server , In File location step I have given C drive unknowingly, Is there any procedure to move all SharePoint files ( program files, Microsoft office servers, 15.0, Office) to my D drive. If yes please let me know the procedure.

Comment: SharePoint always install on C drive, why would you move it to D drive?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things.

- you can't change the installation location after the install or move the files.

Now you have two things.

- Change The Logs File Location From C Drive To D drive, You Can Do Via Central Admin Under Monitoring.
- also change the it's log location from c to d using the iis.

But if you want move everything from c to d,then you have to re install sharepoint. But keep in mind 14/15/16 hives folder always on c drive,you can't change them.